# How to save a jsoup document as text file

Tags: java, text, jsoup, document

I am trying to save all of the readable words on a web page into one text document while ignoring html markup. 
Using JSoup to parse all of the words on a webpage, my only guess of how to seperate the real words from the code is through elements.

Is it possible to convert multiple elements of the jsoup document into a text file?

i.e.:

```
        Elements titles = doc.select("title");
        Elements paragraphs = doc.select("p");
        Elements links = doc.select("a[href]"); 
        Elements smallText = doc.select("a");
```

Currently saving the parse as a document with:

```
 Document doc = Jsoup.connect("https:// (enter a url)").get();
```

Comment: Just create a file and write to it???

Comment: sorry, I'm new to java and I'm still trying to figure things out. Can you show me a sample code or a reference that can teach me how to do that?

Comment: Here is the best place to learn about Java old and new IO APIs https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/

Comment: thank you. I will be sure to read through it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its simple way

```
Document doc = Jsoup.connect("https:// (enter a url)").get();
        BufferedWriter  writer = null;
        try
        {
            writer = new BufferedWriter( new FileWriter("d://test.txt"));
            writer.write(doc.toString());

        }
        catch ( IOException e)
        {
        }
```

Comment: Thank you! I tested this and it works. How would I save only certain elements to that file writer though? Example is in the main post now.

Comment: So you want to save everything one by one in the file ?

Comment: I am trying to save all of the readable words on a web page into one text document while ignoring html markup. that's what the elements are for, to select only readable words.

Comment: You can create a list of` elements`  and `iterate in the file`

Answer (score -1):

Adding answer because I am unable to comment above.

Replace `writer.write(doc.toString());` by  `writer.write(doc.select("html").text());` in the above code.

It will give you the text on the page.

Instead of `"html"` in `doc.select("**html**").text()` other tags can be used to extract text enclosed in those tags.

Edit: you can also use `writer.write(doc.body().text());`

Comment: this parses it with all of the html markup though; it doesn't exclude the enclosed tags <etc> .. how can i only extract real words?

Comment: Using `doc.select("html").toString()` will return web element as a String, here tags won't be excluded. I suggest `"html"` tag as it is the root tag in html document(wep page). If `doc.select("html").text()` doesn't work for you(it should though) try `doc.body().text()`

Comment: whenever I use .text() at the end it just saves a blank .txt file

Comment: Did you try printing the output, maybe some error in writing to text file.

Answer (score -1):

After writing in the text with `writer.write(doc.text());` the very next line you need to write `writer.close();` this will fix the problem.

Comment: Please suggest this as an edit on the other answer instead of adding the comment as a new answer.