# How can I get the LineNumber of the element when using Jsoup?

Tags: java, parsing, jsoup, element

such as:

```
Document doc = Jsoup.parse(file,"UTF-8");

Elements eles = doc.getElementsByTag("style");
```

How can I get the lineNumber of `eles[0]` in the file?

Comment: You may use the regular expression.

Comment: So,if jsoup can not do that,what can I use to parse html and get the LineNumber of an element?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way for you to do it with Jsoup API. I have checked on their source code: `org.jsoup.parser.Parser` maintains no position information of the element in the original input.

Please, refer to [sources](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.jsoup/jsoup/1.8.2/org/jsoup/Jsoup.java?av=f) on Grep Code

Provided that [Jsoup](https://jsoup.org/) is build for extracting and **manipulating** data I don't believe that they will have such feature in future as it is ambigous what element position is after manipulation and costly to maintain actual references.

Answer (score 1):

There is no direct way. But there is an indirect way.
Once you find the point of interest like an attribute, simply add a token as html before the element, and write the file to another temporary file. The next step is do a search for the token, using text editing tools.

code is as follows.

### Step-1:

// get an element 
for (Element element : doc.getAllElements()) {  
... some code to get attributes of element ...

String myAttr = attribute.getKey(); 
if (myAttr.equals("*some-attribute-name-of-interest*") { 
  System.out.println(attribute.getKey() + "::" + attribute.getValue()); 
  element.before("<!-- My Special Token : ABCDEFG -->"); 
}

### Step-2:

// write the doc back to a temporary file 
// see: [How to save a jsoup document as text file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43085465/how-to-save-a-jsoup-document-as-text-file)

### Step-3:

The last step is search for "My Special Token : ABCDEFG" in the output file using  a text editing tool.

jsoup is a nice library. I thought this would help others.