# Jsoup will not save changes made to HTML

Tags: java, html, jsoup

I am trying to alter an HTML file called `results.html` and changing the ID tag `result` from a "come back later" text to an output from my program. I can tell I'm opening the file because it is reading the current HTML "come back later" from `system.out.print`. But nothing is saved in the end

Any tips?

```
Document document = Jsoup.parse( new File( "C:\\Users\\ctisi\\Documents\\results.html" ) , "utf-8" );
Element resultID = document.getElementById("result");
System.out.println("Outer HTML Before Modification :\n"  + resultID.outerHtml());
resultID.text("This is a sample content.");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are modifying the *in memory* representation of the DOM structure as represented by the `document` object. This will not alter the output file.

You will need to actually add code to *write* the modified document back to the file.

```java
File file=new File("C:\\Users\\ctisi\\Documents\\results.html");
Document document=Jsoup.parse(file , "utf-8" );
Element resultID=document.getElementById("result");
resultID.text("This is a sample content.");
FileWriter writer=new FileWriter(file);
writer.write(document.toString());
writer.flush();
writer.close();
```

Comment: Perhaps this answer will help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43085465/how-to-save-a-jsoup-document-as-text-file

Comment: I updated my answer to show a way to write the output.